# AngularJS UI Bootstrap Datepicker Not opening next time after clicking outside

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI bootstrap with AngularJS. The version I'm susing is **0.11.0**.

I have used few directives of it and I'm trying to use the date picker. In some cases I have many date pickers need in one form or I may need a date range.

I have a text field, with an icon inside the text field. Whenever any of the item is clicked I'm opening the date picker. If I select any date, it's working fine and closing the datepicker.

But if I click outside of date picker, it's hiding the datepicker. But then if I try again to open the date picker it is not opening.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-7 controls with-icon-over-input padding-top">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                                    ng-model="object.date"
                                    id="date" name="date"
                                    datepicker-popup='yyyy/MM/dd' is-open="opened" ng-click="openDatePicker($event)"
                                    datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" ng-change="close()"
                                    /> <i ng-click="openDatePicker($event)"
                                    class="icon-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
```

And MY **Controller.js** file

has the following

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            'show-weeks':false
    };

//  var datePickerElemet;

    $scope.openDatePicker = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
//      datePickerElemet = $($event.currentTarget).prev();
//      $(datePickerElemet).show();
        $scope.opened = true;
    }

    $scope.close = function() {
        $scope.opened = false;
//      $(datePickerElemet).hide();
    }
```

When I checked it is showing based on *is-opened* as well as block or none. So I tried to show and hide the datepicker on click and change(You can see the code commented). But the problem is the date picker is not hiding when I click outside as the display is block always. The default buttons (Close, today and clear) will work first time, but then next time if I try, it is setting values or clearing, but not hiding the date picker if I set the display block.

Here is what I import my JS files

```
<script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- build:js scripts/ngscripts.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- / jquery ui -->
<script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I solve? Is there anything more I want to import?

I have added what I'm doing in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m6lslz6zHn2TxyeuvcIq?p=preview), but it's working there

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle or codepen replicating the issue?

Comment: @TonyBarnes I'm trying. In Plunker I saw many examples. I'm following the same way. It's working there but not in my application. Like this http://plnkr.co/edit/sFIJSzuuFUk3uh8MZ8he?p=preview

Comment: @TonyBarnes I have added the code in http://plnkr.co/edit/m6lslz6zHn2TxyeuvcIq?p=preview And it's working there

Comment: There must be something else causing this issue. I've tried adding a few of the components you're using, it would be great if you could replicate the exact code/components in the plunker so we can debug.

Comment: @TonyBarnes only that's it.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue.

Comment: @TonyBarnes Even I'm not understandfing what's causing problem in my application.

Comment: Without having it replicated outside of your local machine, there is nothing we can do to debug. I can only suggest removing as much as you can from the app that isn't related to the datepicker (it should work after this), then, add components back in one-by-one, and see when it breaks. Then, you will know where the problem comes from.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I'm now implementing clickoutside directive so that when clicking outisde it will hide the datepicker. May be it's conflicting with other directives or something.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "IN" your Plunker code.

You have all you need in THAT code to get it to work, you don't need to import anything else, or change anything in that code.

BUT...it's what is not in your Plunker code that is causing the problem.  Additional datepickers, textboxes, class styling rules, javascript, other events or setting values... ect.  If you simplify your code until it works, and add back in the additional stuff until it breaks, you will see what is causing the issue.

Are you sure you don't have additional code you are not showing us?  It's possible there is a problem in your scope.

[Here](https://cheonhyangzhang.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/bootstrap-ui-datepicker-only-open-once-not-shown-up-the-second-time/#comments) is a solution to a similar problem...

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment practically saying exactly the same as what has been discussed in the comments.

Comment: His questions are: "How can I solve? Is there anything more I want to import?"  This answers both of those questions.  Nothing more to import, and to solve it he needs to use the simple code that works on plunker.  He claims there is nothing more then what is shown here.  If that is the case, then problem solved.  I know you agree with that.  The comments, and his response do a great job of pointing that out.  And to your point, yes, the answer is also in the comments, but that's not where answers go... ;)